# ASP.NET MVC append div to body

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I make a customize controller about calendar. But a div required  to append to body.  I search,but get nothing . The following code what I implement  works,but not fine. I figure out that, div should be put to the end of body ,just like `jquery $('body').append('div')` But I don't know how to code in MVC helper.

```
  public static MvcHtmlString CalendarTextBox(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, DateTime? value, DateTime start, DateTime max, string nextTriggerId, object htmlAttributes = null)
            {
                var result = helper.TextBox(name, value, htmlAttributes);
                var str = result.ToHtmlString().Replace(@"/>", string.Format(@"  mod=""calendar|notice"" 
       mod_notice_tip=""yyyy-mm-dd"" 
      mod_calendar_rangeStart=""{0}"" 
      mod_calendar_rangeEnd=""{1}""
      mod_calendar_focusNext=""{2}"" //>", start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), max.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), nextTriggerId));

                if (null == helper.ViewData["calendar"])
                {
                    str += string.Format(
                       @"<div style=""HEIGHT: 0px""id=""jsContainer""class=""jsContainer""><div style=""DISPLAY: none""id=""jsHistoryDiv""></div><textarea style=""DISPLAY: none""id=""jsSaveStatus""></textarea><div style=""Z-INDEX: 999; POSITION: absolute; DISPLAY: none; OVERFLOW: hidden""
    id=""tuna_alert""></div><div style=""Z-INDEX: 120; POSITION: absolute; VISIBILITY: hidden""
    id=""tuna_jmpinfo""></div><div style=""Z-INDEX: 120; POSITION: absolute; DISPLAY: none""id=""tuna_calendar""
    class=""tuna_calendar""></div></div><SCRIPT type=text/javascript charset=utf-8 src=""{0}/js/datepicker/tuna_100324_jsLoader.js""></script><script type=""text/javascript"">var JL=new CtripJsLoader();var files=[[""{0}/js/datepicker/tuna_100324_index.js"",""utf-8"",true]];JL.scriptAll(files);</script>",
                       Define.ASSET_PATH);
                    helper.ViewData["calendar"] = 1;
                }
                return MvcHtmlString.Create(str);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inject the `$('body').append('div');` line into the generated HTML and nest the statement within a javascript block within the document ready function:

```
// ...
str += string.Format(
    @"<script type=""text/javascript"">$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').append('div'); } </script>");

helper.ViewData["calendar"] = 1;
// ...
```